# Convert decimal time to use in QGIS

Tags: qgis, convert, time, double

I have a .shp file with includes a column of format Double that is the Arrival time.

The time values entered are decimal time. For instance, 1 record has a decimal time of 7.11194, which converts to 07:06:43

What is the easiest method to convert this value so I can use it in QGIS?

I've tried using the totime value in QGIS, but no luck.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'd simply go for "manual" conversion, aka build a field calculator expression and be done with it. Do you have to repeat this process?

Answer (score 7):

Wow this is very fun and... extremely hard for me. Assuming `"arrival"` as your Arrival time field:

Hour........... `lpad(to_string(floor("arrival")),2,0)`

Minutes...... `lpad(to_string((floor("arrival"*60)%60)),2,0)`

Seconds..... `lpad(to_string(round(("arrival"*3600)%60)),2,0)`

Wrapping the above into single expression, it becomes:

```
lpad(to_string(floor("arrival")),2,0) || ':' || lpad(to_string((floor("arrival"*60)%60)),2,0) || ':' || lpad(to_string(round(("arrival"*3600)%60)),2,0)
```

Hope you'll get better answers.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delay, this is the first time i've had the chance to try your suggestion, but it has worked I'm not a programmer by any stretch of the imagination; I can do some basic stuff in MapInfo and QGIS, but this had me stumped once trying the totime syntax in qgis failed
Thank-you for your assistance regards

Comment: You can omit `to_string()` here, as `lpad()` automatically transforms the field value into a string.